# Getting address of caller in c++

Tags: c++, windows

At the moment I'm working on a anticheat. I added a way to detect any hooking to the directx functions, since those are what most cheats do.

The problem comes in when a lot of programs, such as OBS, Fraps and many other programs that hook directx get their hook detected too.

So to be able to hook directx, you will most probabbly have to call VirtualProtect. If I could determine what address this is being called from, then I could loop through all dll's in memory, and then find what module it has been called from, and then sending the information to the server, maybe perhaps even taking a md5 hash and sending it to the server for validation.

I could also hook the DirectX functions that the cheats hook and check where those get called from (since most of them use ms detours).

I looked it up, and apparently you can check the call stack, but every example I found did not seem to help me.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the DirectX hooks actually patch the in memory vtable of the DirectX object(s). Shouldn't it be possible to check if the memory addresses of the vtable methods are still original or point to a whitelisted module?

Comment: @dhke yeah, my vtable hooking has its filters and its working like a charm, but the problem is the detour hooking one.

Answer (score 1):

This -**getting the caller's address- is not possible in standard C++**. And many C++ compilers might optimize some calls (e.g. by inlining them, even when you don't specify `inline`, or because there is no more any framepointer, e.g. compiler option `-fomit-frame-pointer`for x86 32 bits with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), or by optimizing a [tail-call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) ....) to the point that the question might not make any sense.

With some implementations and some C or C++ standard libraries and some (but not all) compiler options (in particular, don't ask the compiler to optimize too much<sup>*</sup>) you might get it, e.g. (on Linux) use [`backtrace` from GNU *glibc*](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) or [I.Taylor's `libbacktrace` (from inside GCC implementation)](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libbacktrace) or GCC [return address builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html#Return-Address).

<sup>I don't know how difficult would it be to port these to Windows (Perhaps Cygwin did it). The GCC builtins might somehow work, if you don't optimize too much.</sup>

Read also about [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation). See also [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/286559/40065) to a related question.

Note *: on Linux, better compile all the code (including external libraries!) with at most `g++ -Wall -g -O1` : you don't want too much optimization, and you want the debug information (in particular for `libbacktrace`)

Comment: You don't get a choice about what switches someone else compiles their code with. The detecting code can make sure it has good backtrace information for its own code, but eventually it will reach 3rd party code.

Comment: If the external library is a free software, you could recompile it.

Comment: The OP is talking about games using DirectX and being hooked by random DLLs from all over the place. Now these DLLs might have their source available, but it's unlikely (FRAPS isn't, for example). DirectX isn't open-source. The games are probably not open-source (if they were, why would I go to the trouble of hooking DirectX calls for cheating instead of just modifying the source?). And Linux flags are irrelevant anyway when the question is tagged Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Ray Chen's blog 'The old new thing' covers using return address' to make security decisions and why its a pretty pointless thing

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060203-00/?p=32403

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040101-00/?p=41223

Basically its pretty easy to fake (by injecting code or using a manually constructed fake stack to trick you). Its Windows centric but the basic concepts are generally applicable.